# PHP Transforming the String

Tags: php, string

I have a string: `$str = 'hello-all-the-world'`. I would like to transform this string to `Hello, all, the & world`. So, basically just before the last word of string, it should have `&` and others should join by `,`!

I tried the following:

```
<?php

$str = 'hello-all-the-world';

$arr = explode('-', $str);

// lost from here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this, if you cut off the last array element after splitting using array_pop - then you implode what’s left using `,`, and add the final element again after an `&`:

```
$str = 'hello-all-the-world';

$arr = explode('-', $str);
$last = array_pop($arr); // pop last item from array

echo implode(', ', $arr) . ' &amp; ' . $last;

// result: hello, all, the & world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<?php

$str = 'hello-all-the-world';

$arr = explode('-', $str);
$last = array_pop($arr);
$ans = implode(', ', $arr) . ' & ' . $last;
```